# sf appears to truncate a projection string

Tags: r, sp, sf

Curious how folks deal with this type of thing where `sf` appears to trim the spatial projection:

```
library(sf)
library(sp)
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE)
st_crs(nc)$proj4string
[1] "+proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs"

nc_sp <- as(nc, "Spatial")
proj4string(nc_sp)
[1] "+proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs +ellps=clrk66 +nadgrids=@conus,@alaska,@ntv2_0.gsb,@ntv1_can.dat"
```

I am wanting to check if two projections are the same and I am running into this type of sf behaviour where the projections are the same but the strings aren't . Obviously I can deal with this via string manipulation but I am wondering if there is a more robust solution when projection strings are slightly different because of this type of truncation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
> nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE)
```

it looks to me like its only reading in what's in the `nc.prj`, namely only the proj, datum and no_defs parameters:

```
> st_crs(nc)
Coordinate Reference System:
  EPSG: 4267 
  proj4string: "+proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs"
```

Converting with `as(nc, "Spatial")`, or reading it in with `raster::shapefile`, or `readOGR` is processing the projection string and adding the `nadgrids`. You can make `sf` do this by setting the CRS from the proj4string version of itself:

```
> st_crs(nc) = st_crs(nc)$proj4string
Warning message:
st_crs<- : replacing crs does not reproject data; use st_transform for that
```

and now....

```
> st_crs(nc)
Coordinate Reference System:
  EPSG: 4267 
  proj4string: "+proj=longlat +ellps=clrk66 +nadgrids=@conus,@alaska,@ntv2_0.gsb,@ntv1_can.dat +no_defs"
```

replacing using the EPSG numeric code in a proj4string:

```
> nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE)
> st_crs(nc)
Coordinate Reference System:
  EPSG: 4267 
  proj4string: "+proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs"
```

like this

```
> st_crs(nc) = "+init=epsg:4267"
Warning message:
st_crs<- : replacing crs does not reproject data; use st_transform for that
```

adds the nadgrids:

```
> st_crs(nc)
Coordinate Reference System:
  EPSG: 4267 
  proj4string: "+proj=longlat +ellps=clrk66 +nadgrids=@conus,@alaska,@ntv2_0.gsb,@ntv1_can.dat +no_defs"
>
```

But replacing via a plain numeric code doesn't:

```
> nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE)
> st_crs(nc) = st_crs(nc)$epsg
> st_crs(nc)
Coordinate Reference System:
  EPSG: 4267 
  proj4string: "+proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs"
```

I think because `st_crs<-` thinks its the same CRS as before, so there's no warning and no change in anything. Weird. Anyway, replacing with a proj4string always seems to result in an expansion of the projection to include nadgrids components...

Comment: Indeed weird but this is a great breakdown here. Thanks @Spacedman!

Comment: sf uses GDAL's crs->IsSame(other), see https://www.gdal.org/classOGRSpatialReference.html#a17fd82b2f58a976a30358b076a2fc966 for details. This is obviously not without flaws, and I'm not sure whether the problem is unambiguous. Hopefully https://gdalbarn.com/ will, once released, improve things.